# Azure AD and connecting to AWS RDS using IAM and personal profiles

Tags: azure-active-directory, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I have Azure AD with SSO integrated to AWS. I am using [aws-azure-login](https://github.com/dtjohnson/aws-azure-login) to login to AWS CLI, and I would like to connect to RDS (MySQL Aurora) without using shared profile - mostly to have some audit trail and to see who has done something.

I am able to login to RDS with these [instructions](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/), but I don't find any way to use Azure integration with this. One way to get this done would be creating invidual profiles/roles for each person into IAM and adding them into the /.aws/configuration files, but that would take a lot of time and it wouldn't really make use of the Azure integration.

Is there any way to do this? To get individual profiles from Azure AD to AWS IAM, or any other way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

It is in their roadmap for PostgreSQL, no information on whether or not this feature will become available for Aurora MySQL anytime soon.